# PHP Contact Form Won't Send To AOL Email

Tags: php, forms, email

I've made a basic PHP contact form adapted from some open source code I found, the site just was published, and now I'm having an issue. Mainly, the form seems to work but the email is not arriving in my client's inbox.

I sent a test email to my client using their email as the recipient, and they say they haven't received it. However, when I substitute my own email it comes to my inbox just fine. It might be worth noting that the client has an AOL email address - could it be that AOL blocks this? I've had them check their spam folder, they still say they can't see it.

I've checked my code for issues, and I'm baffled what is going on here. I've used a similar form with adjustments for other sites I've made with no issues.

The HTML form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="mailer.php"      class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPhone" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Your Telephone Number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Message Subject">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your Message..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    Send Message
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "clientsemail@aol.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$phone = check_input($_POST['inputPhone'], "Your Telephone Number");
$subject = check_input($_POST['inputSubject'], "Message Subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Inquiry from Website";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your website's contact form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Telephone: $phone
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location:    http://www.theclientswebsite.com/confirmation.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd like to flag this because any one that's written a form mailer in the last dozen years knows how hateful AOL mail can be, but instead I'll welcome you into the wonderful world that is telling your client that their email provider is blocking this before it even gets to them and there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Hi the_pete...well...I've only been making websites for 3 years, so I must have missed that memo! Thanks for enlightening me. :) All the research I've done in the past 30 minutes supports your comment...<groan> now how to break it to the client? I've just done a redesign of their site, which the previous designer made with Joomla...and I assume their email was working. Or maybe it wasn't all along? Who knows...

Comment: This isn't something specific to AOL either, know that. Comcast, SBGlobal, Netrunner, the list goes on all do the same thing. They love to hide behind their primary spam filters and kind of make it a "pay to play" thing, which is why services like MailChimp and Constant Contact are a necessary evil. They are permanently white listed with these guys.

Comment: If the problem is that the mail is being rejected, adding a from header might help with that.